# Как лучше реализовать предпросмотр результата?

Tags: javascript, php, css

пишу метод, редактирующий картинку с помощью php библиотеки imageMagick (контраст, оттенок, яркость) и возник вопрос:

как лучше выводить предпросмотр картинки пользователю?

1. с помощью js крутить параметры css, а после нажатия кнопки сохранения применять параметры (отображать в реальном времени)
2. сохранить оригинал картинки, отображать копию для сравнения с оригиналом (примерно как [здесь](https://phpimagick.com/Imagick/brightnessContrastImage))

Comment: А вы в курсе что все это (редактир-ие картинок) давно можно делать на клиенте? не нагружая сервер.

Comment: @hindmost, каким образом с помощью php imageMagick можно делать редактирование картинок на стороне клиента?

Comment: imageMagick - для сервера. на клиенте - [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). Если не хотите вникать в Canvas, есть множество открытых библиотек для работы с картинками. гугл в помощь.

Comment: @hindmost, окей, спасибо. учту в будущих проектах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в итоге сделал и так, и так.

как идеологически правильно - вероятно, зависит от обстоятельств.